# Postgress query, group by, and show the latest timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am making queries on a single table that contains a timestamp.

My current query is the next one

```
SELECT MAX (time) as MostRecentDate, name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy
FROM margintest
WHERE country = 'DK' AND fromcurrency = 'DKK' AND tocurrency = 'EUR'
GROUP BY name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy;
```

How can I display the value of exchangeratebuy in this query without Gruoping by exchangeratebuy?

I want to make something like:

```
SELECT MAX (time) as MostRecentDate, name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy
FROM margintest
WHERE country = 'DK' AND fromcurrency = 'DKK' AND tocurrency = 'EUR'
GROUP BY name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency;
```

But this gives me a error tha the selected column also need to be groupe by.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON` if you want one record *per group*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy)
       time as MostRecentDate, name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy
FROM margintest
WHERE country = 'DK' AND fromcurrency = 'DKK' AND tocurrency = 'EUR'
ORDER BY BY name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy, time DESC;
```

The "group" is defined by all the initial columns.  The last column defines *which* row is taken from the group.

In your case, you may want just one row.  For that, you can also use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
       time as MostRecentDate, name, country, tocurrency, fromcurrency, exchangeratebuy
FROM margintest
WHERE country = 'DK' AND fromcurrency = 'DKK' AND tocurrency = 'EUR'
ORDER BY BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```